# Why can't I initialize list with another object in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python.

I would like to initialize a list with another object.
However compiler tells me it is an syntax error.

```
string='b'
string_list_direct=['a' 'b']  # ok
string_list=['a' string]  # syntax error
```

Why can't I initialize a list with another object?

error message is following

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Or `'a' + string`, not clear what you expect as output...

Comment: Space separated string literals happen to be a specific supported syntax. `'a' string` however is nonsense.

Comment: `'a' 'b'` is the same as `'ab'`.

Comment: @deceze: thank you for telling me the reason why the compiler did not make an error with the first example. By the way, what should I do for 'put on hold'? Do I need to delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the comma on the list.

`string_list = ['a',string]`

The following works:

`string = 'f'
 string_list = ['a',string]
string_list
['a', 'f']`